# Error when reading a Pdf file from internal memory?

Tags: java, android, file, pdf

I am trying to read a pdf file from internal memory of the device my code is here:

```
                File pdfFile;    

            pdfFile=new File("data/data/com.myapp.main/app_c"+md+"/c"+md+".pdf");


                 if(pdfFile.exists()) 
                 {
                     try{
                      FileOutputStream fileOutput = openFileOutput(pdfFile.toString(), Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
                     }
                     catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                         e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                     Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile); 
                 Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                 pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
                 pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                 try
                 {
                     startActivity(pdfIntent);
                 }
                 catch(ActivityNotFoundException e)
                 {
                     Toast.makeText(ChTable.this, "No Application available to view pdf", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 }
```

But the Pdf reader shows an Error -File not supported-Or File Not found .But I have checked that file is there at this location.I have also changed the permission to the file ,but still the same result. Would Someone help me detect and solve my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use PDFBox library to read data from pdf -

http://pdfbox.apache.org/

Answer (score 0):

```
data/data/com.myapp.main/app_c"+md+"/c"+md+".pdf"
```

Is this path  correct?

I am guessing the path should be like below.

```
data/data/com/myapp/main/app_c"+md+"/c"+md+".pdf"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using one of the apis to get the application's files directory rather than assuming what the path will be.

Your actual problem however is most likely that any file you create there is probably private to the owning application, so the PDF reader app lacks permission to access it.

Solutions to that would be to change the file mode to world readable, or more commonly to put the file on the external storage (ie, "sdcard") rather than the internal memory, as that does not (to date) have a concept of permissions.  Though it's worth remembering that a device isn't guaranteed to have an external storage, or for it to be accessible at any given point in time even if it exists.